# Integrating an API in flutter app gives error "Program linking failed"

Tags: android, api, http, flutter, dart

When I try to integrate with API in flutter app getting an error "`Program linking failed`"

**Log**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
D/EGL_emulation( 7612): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe30bcb00: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3610f50)
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
I/chatty  ( 7612): uid=10086(com.example.on_demand_customer) 1.gpu identical 9 lines
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed.
E/flutter ( 7612): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 192.168.2.20, port = 42460
```

Comment: Hi @Pro_Jey.Welcome to SO :). Can you provide more information about the problem you facing like which API, Implementation code if possible (remove any private information), and try to use Formatting to make the question more readable.

Comment: Hi, @magic_man I don't have any errors in code, because in Ubuntu my code working fine. when I try to run my code in windows 10 only getting error it's saying like "D/skia    ( 7612): Program linking failed".

Comment: Does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqL1INnJrLY) help you or otherwise explains your problem?

Comment: Can you show us the result of `flutter doctor -v` ?

Comment: yeah I've fixed that error it's a proxy error thanks for your response @Muldec

Answer (score 1):

It's just a proxy error it will happen only when your server and android studio is connected  with proxy and your pc doesn't connect with a proxy then only you will get an error like this

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp8FD.png`enter code here`